# node.js express custom format debug logging

Tags: node.js, logging, express

A seemingly simple question, but I am unsure of the node.js equivalent to what I'm used to (say from Python, or LAMP), and I actually think there may not be one.

Problem statement: I want to use basic, simple logging in my express app. Maybe I want to output DEBUG messages, or INFO messages, or just some stats to the log for consumption by other back-end systems later.

1) I want all logs message, however, to contain some fields: remote-ip and request url, for example.

2) On the other hand, code that logs is everywhere in my app, including deep inside the call tree.

3) I don't want to pass `(req,res)` down into every node in the call tree (this just creates a lot of parameter passing where they are mostly not needed, and complicates my code, as I need to pass these into async callbacks and timeouts etc.)

In other systems, where there is a thread per request, I will store the (req,res) pair (where all the data I need is) in a thread-local-storage, and the logger will read this and format the message.

In node, there is only one thread. What is my alternative here? What's "the request context in which a specific piece of code is running under"?

The only way I can think of achieving something like this is by looking at a trace, and using reflection to look at local variables up the call tree. I hate that, plus would need to implement this for all callbacks, setTimeouts, setIntervals, new Function()'s, eval's, ... and the list goes on.

What are other people doing?

Comment: You know that any functions defined within a function share the outer function's variables? So you could store the preamble to your log messages in the request handler and all the defined callbacks within that request handler can refer to the preamble variable you defined.

Comment: Yes, but what about function b called from within a, but not defined inside a? And what about callbacks? and timeouts? (and the less common cases of functions constructed in runtime, or eval code, god forbid?)

Comment: Function b needs data passed to it - or belong to an object you created.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I was trying to avoid. Explicitly passing `(req,res)` to pretty much every function I call (because who knows, it might call other functions that will need to use logging). I wish there was a better way of associating running code to the request it is running on behalf. I suggested something in my original post, but it would be too cumbersome to write just for logging, I suppose.

Comment: Your callback functions could be defined as part of an object that you instantiate upon handling a request. Then they could refer to `this` and an object member for your preamble.